# How is the 'name' attribute calculated in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to understand how the 'name' attribute works for elements in markup rendered via ASP.NET

I.e. `<select id="lblxyz" name="ctl00$c$ctl341$lblxyz">`

What are  `ctl00`, `c` and `ctl1341`?

If I create a `WebControl`, give it an arbitrary id, then place a `Button` inside its `Controls` collection, the `name` attribute does not seem to reflect the container's id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing as you have discovered is that not all controls trigger this behaviour. The key is the [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) interface. Only Naming Containers will contribute to the name of the control as you have seen, other controls won't.

The MSDN page linked above says it pretty well: that interface "identifies a container control that creates a new ID namespace within a Page object's control hierarchy."

Answer (score 1):

The generated name attribute typically always starts with `ctl00`, and the rest is generated based on where the control lives in the control hierarchy. Any parent controls implementing the `INamingContainer` interface will contribute to the names generated for any child controls.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of interest to you, it outlines out the id/names are generated: http://www.mostlylucid.net/archive/2008/11/03/way-too-much-information-on-control-ids-and-asp.net-4.0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can control how the client ID appears using the new ClientIDMode:

[All about Client ID Mode in ASP.NET 4](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/61/posts/11206/all-about-client-id-mode-in-aspnet-4.aspx)